# specify sysctl values using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set a few sysctl values.
Basically the following

```
sysctl -w \
   net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=300 \
   net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60 \
   net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=9
```

in a docker container.
When log into to the container directly and execute the command, I get the following error

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes: No such file or directory
```

Then I found out the --sysctl option in `docker run` in [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)
But I did not find the equivalent option via docker-compose. 
I have few services that start by default so using docker run instead of docker-compose is not an option for me.

Anyone knows of a way to supply --sysctl options to the container via compose?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This option is now available in docker-compose 1.10.0-rc1, you'll need to upgrade to that version (`pip install docker-compose==1.10.0-rc1`) and also update your `docker-compose.yml` file to version 2.1 per [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/version-21)

Example docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    app:
        build: .
        sysctls:
            - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't seem possible to specify it for builds... I need it at build time to disable IPv6, otherwise building images based on old Debian versions takes forever. :(

Comment: If you build the container you must disable it on the building host.

Answer (score 2):

docker-compose lacks many of the CLI options. In general, you have to head over to the [github issues for compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues) and search there. In the case of `sysctl`, it's in the process of being added. Someone has [made a branch with the addition](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3765). You could start with that until it gets added to the master branch.