# docker-compose up airflow-init hangs: no network connection between containers

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, airflow

I'm trying to set up airflow instance using docker-compose as described in [official docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html) and I'm stuck at airflow-init part.  It looks like there is no connectivity between containers, but I don't know how to fix it.

I use literally the same `docker-compose.yaml` as described in docs.  It can be downloaded here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml

Currently, I see this in my shell:

```
~/dwn $ docker-compose up airflow-init
51ad8448b197_dwn_redis_1 is up-to-date
70409dec742c_dwn_postgres_1 is up-to-date
Starting dwn_airflow-init_1 ... done
Attaching to dwn_airflow-init_1
airflow-init_1       | BACKEND=postgresql+psycopg2
airflow-init_1       | DB_HOST=postgres
airflow-init_1       | DB_PORT=5432
```

Docs says I should see somethings like this:

```
airflow-init_1       | Upgrades done
airflow-init_1       | Admin user airflow created
airflow-init_1       | 2.1.2
start_airflow-init_1 exited with code 0
```

but that command just hangs and never exits.  Htop shows me that netcat is running inside this container and it is trying to connect to postgres:

```
nc -zvvn 172.19.0.3 5432
```

`curl` shows timeout:

```
~/dwn $ docker exec -it dwn_airflow-init_1 curl postgres:5432
curl: (7) Failed to connect to postgres port 5432: Connection timed out
```

Why it hangs?

---

I tried a few things to fix this:

1. I tried setting `ports` option in `postgres` service to `5432:5432` - no effect
2. I tried setting `links` option - no effect
3. [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68172225/9069666) suggested system entropy is too low - no, there is plenty of entropy
4. There is enough free RAM, CPU, disk space
5. I tried setting network like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55678441/9069666) - it is even worse, containter names aren't resolved:

   ```
   ~/dwn $ docker exec -it dwn_airflow-init_1 curl postgres:5432
   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: postgres
   ```
6. I tried resetting iptables like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62433399) - no effect

---

Some system info:

- OS: Arch Linux
- docker version: 20.10.7, build f0df35096d
- docker-compose version: 1.29.2

---

Logs! (as requested by @larsks)

```
~/dwn $ docker-compose ps
       Name                     Command                  State                        Ports                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dwn_airflow-init_1   /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /ent ...   Up             8080/tcp                                
dwn_postgres_1       docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up (healthy)   5432/tcp                                
dwn_redis_1          docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp,:::6379->6379/tcp
~/dwn $ docker-compose logs postgres
Attaching to dwn_postgres_1
postgres_1           | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres_1           | This user must also own the server process.
postgres_1           | 
postgres_1           | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres_1           | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres_1           | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres_1           | 
postgres_1           | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres_1           | 
postgres_1           | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgres_1           | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgres_1           | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgres_1           | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgres_1           | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgres_1           | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgres_1           | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres_1           | running bootstrap script ... ok
postgres_1           | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
postgres_1           | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres_1           | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgres_1           | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgres_1           | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgres_1           | 
postgres_1           | 
postgres_1           | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres_1           | 
postgres_1           |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgres_1           | 
postgres_1           | waiting for server to start....2021-07-17 07:31:38.491 UTC [47] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:31:38.493 UTC [47] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:31:38.499 UTC [48] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-07-17 07:31:35 UTC
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:31:38.521 UTC [47] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1           |  done
postgres_1           | server started
postgres_1           | CREATE DATABASE
postgres_1           | 
postgres_1           | 
postgres_1           | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
postgres_1           | 
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:31:39.613 UTC [47] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres_1           | waiting for server to shut down....2021-07-17 07:31:39.615 UTC [47] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:31:39.616 UTC [47] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54) exited with exit code 1
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:31:39.616 UTC [49] LOG:  shutting down
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:31:39.644 UTC [47] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres_1           |  done
postgres_1           | server stopped
postgres_1           | 
postgres_1           | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres_1           | 
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:31:39.741 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:31:39.741 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:31:39.741 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:31:39.748 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:31:39.756 UTC [75] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-07-17 07:31:39 UTC
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:31:39.781 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:33:49.955 UTC [79] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:34:00.040 UTC [79] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:34:00.049 UTC [235] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
postgres_1           | 2021-07-17 07:34:10.141 UTC [79] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
```

When I edit `postgres` service to make it accessible from host (`ports` option) I can see it really is there

```
~/dwn $ pg_isready -h localhost -p 5432
localhost:5432 - accepting connections
```

---

Here is how network created by docker-compose looks like:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "dwn_default",
        "Id": "8c4e4ab1629cd7d2cb5d532e28b0837a11bc3516ba094248294e5d734a69dc11",
        "Created": "2021-07-17T10:15:50.694208715+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "2c6dd1bcd0d81740ab17ff7816acd983ff053be2a8f886ef281b3e5ec1ec642b": {
                "Name": "dwn_airflow-init_1",
                "EndpointID": "945c9bd23ffb52bdee7ae9fdf32f48be623ac73cd60a5b248f919fce6aede366",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "3a79a194d97e491c75e573fa78492c9d4f73efd4d868e709c20eb23c9a0ff2a6": {
                "Name": "dwn_postgres_1",
                "EndpointID": "b3245b8ab82edc78b205485cd39c368881d7c7b2bc29f325fd3f6f6d8605d9c1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "dd023f1d42be72d967c5045b7be29deca88caf99377e7d144c51f2212059cefa": {
                "Name": "dwn_redis_1",
                "EndpointID": "f85a6cd841028efb7fab17e40f814b0d9de300e90f9506df373d973695a38d97",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "dwn",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2"
        }
    }
]
```

---

@jarek-potiuk suggested I should check ipv6 configuration.  Still won't work, but I got some errors this time.  Here is what I did:

I created `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with following content:

```
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8:1::/64"
}
```

This caused following error (after daemon restart):

```
could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv6 address pool among the defaults to as sign to the network
```

This error can be fixed by setting `network_mode: bridge` for every service in compose file and now my services have ipv6 address:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "092767c3c4137429a7caaa85a1b87c7cb977c4f02055624fa84c4d586ed9758f",
        "Created": "2021-07-17T14:42:08.353393246+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": true,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                },
                {
                    "Subnet": "2001:db8:1::/64",
                    "Gateway": "2001:db8:1::1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "964c9edadb8f7eb757cd7f1296c2af154ab407ef4d9872f8e613f61d64d6a443": {
                "Name": "dwn_postgres_1",
                "EndpointID": "a19bd83ff487611e78074eddafbca18e545edcf9ddc9d7851d3b6d68b7962419",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": "2001:db8:1::242:ac11:2/64"
            },
            "b45ca546c1539f5f0f1d76423bd4f071efed2e3d6e118b8811e3fd28164fab5a": {
                "Name": "dwn_airflow-init_1",
                "EndpointID": "3a2fc42dfda6a534b6840971f4b11af9c78aac2253a036f46721ed6e5659f7b9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": "2001:db8:1::242:ac11:4/64"
            },
            "f140d9c90c24fca254e34aec549b559ec5f82bc8b14537e7249192e604110d53": {
                "Name": "dwn_redis_1",
                "EndpointID": "1c26f7afa8ada58626b67e7446347e1c4d540513df72784addcf334f99fd53d1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": "2001:db8:1::242:ac11:3/64"
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

but there is another problem - name resolution stopped working:

```
~/dwn $ docker-compose up airflow-init
dwn_postgres_1 is up-to-date
dwn_redis_1 is up-to-date
Starting dwn_airflow-init_1 ... done
Attaching to dwn_airflow-init_1
airflow-init_1       | BACKEND=postgresql+psycopg2
airflow-init_1       | DB_HOST=postgres
airflow-init_1       | DB_PORT=5432
airflow-init_1       | ....................
airflow-init_1       | ERROR! Maximum number of retries (20) reached.
airflow-init_1       | 
airflow-init_1       | Last check result:
airflow-init_1       | $ run_nc 'postgres' '5432'
airflow-init_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-init_1       |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
airflow-init_1       | socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
airflow-init_1       | Can't parse  as an IP address
airflow-init_1       | 
dwn_airflow-init_1 exited with code 1
```

This is actually documented: [containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52418815/9069666), but access by IP still doesn't work:

```
~/dwn $ docker exec -i -t dwn_airflow-init_1 sh -c 'echo "PING" | nc -v 172.17.0.3 6379'
172.17.0.3: inverse host lookup failed: Host name lookup failure
^C
~/dwn $ echo "PING" | ncat -v localhost 6379
Ncat: Version 7.91 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to ::1:6379.
+PONG
Ncat: 5 bytes sent, 7 bytes received in 0.01 seconds.
```

---

I also found that disabling ipv6 at daemon level does not disable ipv6 in containers, so I tried to disable it in postgres container [by setting sysctls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41496841/9069666).  It works as expected:

```
~/dwn $ docker exec -i -t dwn_postgres_1 cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
1
```

but still no network access.

I'm out of ideas at this point.

Comment: (a) don't use `links`; it's deprecated and never does any good. (b) the `ports` setting has no effect on connections between containers. (c) can you edit your question to include your `docker-compose.yml` file in your question? (d) can you show the logs from your postgres container?

Comment: I use the same `docker-compose.yml` file as linked in official docs.  Also I edited question to add more logs.  (a,b) I'm fairly new to docker, it was just my experiments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured it out myself.

TL;DR: PEBKAC - the user misconfigured firewall and forgot he told the kernel to drop forwarded packets

---

Let's start from the very beginning: `docker-compose up airflow-init` prints just this and waits for something:

```
~/dwn $ docker-compose up airflow-init
51ad8448b197_dwn_redis_1 is up-to-date
70409dec742c_dwn_postgres_1 is up-to-date
Starting dwn_airflow-init_1 ... done
Attaching to dwn_airflow-init_1
airflow-init_1       | BACKEND=postgresql+psycopg2
airflow-init_1       | DB_HOST=postgres
airflow-init_1       | DB_PORT=5432
```

Maybe host `postgres` points to weird place:

```
~/dwn $ docker exec -i -t dwn_airflow-init_1 host postgres
postgres has address 172.20.0.2
```

Not really, looks like any other docker ip, but this netcat invocation still hangs:

```
 nc -zvvn 172.120.0.2 5432
```

That means `postgres` service did not respond at all to airflow init container.  However, `postgres` responded to requests coming from host system.  That means there is no route between `postgres` and `airflow` even if they are in the same network.  Maybe kernel drops forwarded packets?

```
~ # sysctl net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
~ # sysctl net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Forwarding is enabled.  Maybe firewall drops them?

```
~ # iptables -S FORWARD
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o br-b4a6c0b51ae7 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-b4a6c0b51ae7 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-b4a6c0b51ae7 ! -o br-b4a6c0b51ae7 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-b4a6c0b51ae7 -o br-b4a6c0b51ae7 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

It looks like they can get through.  Maybe docker is somehow broken?  Reinstalled, restarted, the same happens.

Maybe iptables is somehow broken?

```
~ # pacman -S iptables
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
:: iptables and iptables-nft are in conflict. Remove iptables-nft? [y/N]
```

Oh.  I have `nftables` installed.  That's weird.  How is my firewall *actually* managed?

```
~ # systemctl status iptables nftables
○ iptables.service - IPv4 Packet Filtering Framework
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

● nftables.service - Netfilter Tables
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nftables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2021-07-19 10:30:41 CEST; 6h ago
       Docs: man:nft(8)
    Process: 824 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nft -f /etc/nftables.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 824 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 9ms
```

And... how forward chain looks like?

```
~ # nft list chain inet filter forward                               
table inet filter {
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        drop
    }
}
```

Hmmm...

Now, what if I delete that chain:

```
~ # nft delete chain inet filter forward
```

Suddenly, airflow starts printing a lot in second terminal.  Goal achieved:

```
airflow-init_1       | Admin user airflow created
airflow-init_1       | 2.1.2
dwn_airflow-init_1 exited with code 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Very detailed analysis. Great to see someone taking that many steps to dig down.

Everything looks good in your setup and logs. So I do not think the problem with docker-compose, it must be a problem with your environment.

I noticed one thing however, and while I am not 100% sure, this might be the reason.

I noticed that your postgres server listens on both IPV4 and IPV6 networks, however your docker-compose networks only show IPV4 addresses.

My hypothesis is that while you have IPV6 enabled for docker engine, it is disabled (or misconfigured) for IPV6.

What would then happen is that when you try to resolve the postgres address using IPV6 resolution and it hangs at retrieving address via misconfigured DNS - hence the timeout.

You can likely set ipv6 to false (https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/) in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and restart the daemon:

```
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8:1::/64"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried that route, but failed - details in my last edit.

Comment: That looks good and kind of confirms my finding. Now ... try to set "ipv6" to "false". And I think it should start working. If this is the case then we might want to try to improve IPV6 compatibility of Airflow.

Comment: I tried both "true" and "false" and both aren't working.

Comment: Can you see if this is really the DNS problem (running `host postgres` should give the answer ? Maybe this is simillar to https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/11407

Comment: Well, I figured it out.  I just assumed firewall rules were managed by iptables, they weren't.